# Can I display a TV channel from TV tuner card using NodeJS for an Electron APP?

Tags: c#, node.js, electron, directx, television

Basically a TV tuner card is connected to the PC and i have to display the TV channel in an electron App.

1. Is there any module in node.js that will help me get this done (in
   C# Directx.DataCapture Class does the job.)
2. If not in node.js then I need to use the DirectX capture class of C# in an 
   electron app with node.js. is this possible ?